# HANA - Filter a projection node with regular expression

Tags: hana

I was wondering how I could filter a column in a `Projection Node` of a `Calculation View` with a regular expression. Currently I know `match` operator, but it is more like a '`LIKE`' SQL operator and **not a regular expression filter**.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graphical calcviews don't allow regex conditions in filters or calculated columns.
You might need to resort to SQL or a table user defined function for that.